# How to define an integer attribute length on Grails (GORM)?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I like to create a domain class with an integer attribute who should be mapped at database with a length of 2, by default GORM creates an INT(11).

Ex:

```
class MyDomain {
    int options
    static constraints = {
        options(min: 0, max: 99, maxSize: 2)
        // options(size: 2) -> Size are not available for integer attribute.
    }
    static mapping = {
        options(length: 2) // Does't work too
    }
}
```

Obs.: I'm using Grails v2.5.2.

Comment: Follow [this documentation](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/column.html), I am sure you will have your answer. :) Also using a primitive type may not be a good idea, try to stick to the wrapper `Integer`.

Comment: Does't work... I have tried to put this:
static mapping = {
    options(length: 2)
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Integer attributes you can use **sqlType** in your mapping :

```
static mapping = {
   options sqlType: 'INT(2)'
}
```

More info you about mapping you can find here : http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.5.1/ref/Database%20Mapping/column.html

Comment: only this option works:
static mapping = {
   options sqlType: 'INT(2)'
}

thnx!!!

Comment: Yes, i believe that size works fine for Strings but my issue was with Integer.